# Is it possible to wrap c++ code in a Kotlin/Native .klib?

Tags: c++, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

The problem is that I am trying to use a C++ library with C headers in iOS, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

If yes. How?

Does anyone have a template for this?

Thanks

EDIT: this answer on Reddit is pretty good for consuming (C++?/C) to a .klib https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/ze1mv9/comment/iz6jav1/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

I still need to figure out how to consume the .klib in iOS

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-c-interop.html

Knowing nothing about Kotlin except that it runs on the JVM: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: You can utilise JNI, it is not something I have experience with but this seems to be a good start: https://jonnyzzz.com/blog/2019/12/15/jni-kotlin/

Comment: Does iOS support JNI?